# Using Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() or updateOne() which pattern selects a child object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

**Environment:** Node.js, Mongoose

I've looked for several hours for an answer but I can't find the pattern that selects a child object when used with, [findOneAndUpdate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) or [updateOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-updateOne).

I've tried the 2 patterns below but neither seem to work.

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: value }, {parent: {child: 'hello world'});
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: value }, {'parent.child': 'hello world'});
```

This basic schema pattern:

```
const MyModelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    parent: {
        child: {
            type: String,
            default: 'example text',
            required: true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you miss operator $set

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: value }, {$set:{'parent.child': 'hello world'}});
```